# Bootstrap Issue, Menu Problems

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I Want to make a menu bar with pictures.
But my pictures dont move.
I think my Bootstrap is false or something other.
I dont find the issue.

It should be look like this:

[This is the Design][1]

```html
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Testing</title>
        <link href="style.css">
        <link href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.js">
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    <div class="container">
    
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="row">
    
            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="img/home.png">
            </div>
        
            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img  src="img/home.png">
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="img/home.png">
            </div>
        
            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="img/home.png">
            </div>
        
            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="img/home.png">
            </div>
    
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand the problem but the pictures probably don't move because of navbar-fixed-top. Also the sum of the cols is higher than 12.

Comment: When you say "But my pictures dont move", you mean there is no scroll ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I don't have any image to use, I replaced it with text. I hope this is what you are looking for

```css
.col-xs-2 {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1">
        <h1> SOME </h1>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <h1> SOME </h1>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <h1> SOME </h1>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <h1> SOME </h1>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <h1> SOME </h1>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now its working! Thanks!! But how can i make the space left go away and how can i choose my own height?

Comment: Remove `col-xs-offset-1` to remove the space in the left side

Comment: Legend! an the height?

Comment: What do you mean by height? Height of what?

Comment: Edited my answer, although I'm sure the height will be provided by the images, unless you want a fixed height.

Comment: Accept and up vote the answer if it helps so that future readers will know what is working for the question stated

Answer (score 0):

I replace `<div class="col-sm-4">` by `<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">`

Bootstrap is based on a 12 column layout.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```